# OwnCloud List All files

Tags: owncloud

I'm doing a data load on OwnCloud of a big number of files for a customer.
I've OwnCloud with the files on S3 in my AWS cloud.
How can I make a list of files to check that all files has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have python at your disposal, install pyocclient library, and use something like this:

```
import owncloud

OWNCLOUD_BASE_URL = "https://your_owncloud_domain_here"

oc = owncloud.Client(OWNCLOUD_BASE_URL,verify_certs=True)
oc.login('login','password')

path = '<your_path_here>'

for element in oc.list(path):
    print(element.path)
```

Comment: I'm using it, very good. But, a question, where owncloud store che structure? Is it on filesystem I think, but for S3 storage?